# Is hardware support for virtual memory necessary to install Linux Operating system on that hardware (processor)?

Tags: memory, hardware, cpu, virtual-memory, hardware-compatibility

Is hardware support for virtual memory necessary to install Linux Operating system on that hardware?

Is it true that Linux Operating System cannot be installed on devices (processors) that do not have MMU (Memory Management Unit) ?

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks... so is it possible for a processor to have virtual memory support and not have a MMU or this is a separate question?

Comment: It’s a separate question, off-topic for Unix.SE, but the answer is that virtual memory requires a MMU (more strictly, any CPU which supports virtual memory will do so using hardware which is effectively a MMU).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you for the information. If I accept the duplicate will people be at least able to comment on the question? I am thinking maybe someone has some additional information to share about this subject.

Comment: Yes, comments are enabled on questions marked as duplicates. Readers can also comment on the linked question (and even provide new answers).

Comment: @StephenKitt Ok I will accept the duplicate now.